# Why embed facebook pages wouldn't work in some of fb-pages

Tags: html, facebook

I've a couple html-codes:
In a facebook page https://www.facebook.com/vuokraahuljufi-265526213476998:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="vuokraahuljufi-265526213476998" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-width="400px" data-height="500px">
```

It works well.

But on a facebook page https://www.facebook.com/talomyynti

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="talomyynti" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-width="400px" data-height="500px">
```

This doen't work. Why. Thank you for a possible simple answers.

Comment: When working with the Facebook GRAPH-API, you can't GET some of the pages because they are only accessible with a valid access-token. Probably it's the same when adding some pages like you do.

Comment: The second page is not fully public, it has some sort of access restriction set. The documentation explicitly mentions that you can't use the Page plugin in such cases, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#privacy